# Kubectl get JSON extracting

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm looking to pull out json information from a yaml file in kubernetes to specifically get the version of the image I'm using. Any help would be awesome.

command I'm using right now is

```
kubectl get statefulset -n namespace -o=jsonpath='{$.spec.template.spec.initcontainers[:1].image}'
```

Comment: Please review the answer suggested if it helped you. Consider accepting if it works.

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution:

```
kubectl get statefulset -n namespace -o=jsonpath='{$.spec.template.spec.containers[*].image}'
```

This also worked:

```
kubectl get statefulset -n namespace -o=jsonpath='{$.spec.template.spec.containers[:1].image}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using item?

```
-o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.template.spec.initcontainers[:1].image}'
```

Comment: yea i tried that and it didnt return anything.

Comment: solution was 
kubectl  get statefulset -n namespace 
-o=jsonpath='{$.spec.template.spec.containers[*].image}'

Comment: @ChawleeJay we advice you to post your comment as an answer so the community will be be able to upvote and also it will be a huge help.

Comment: @ChawleeJay So there is no `initcontainers` section in your `statefulset`?